# SharePoint Picture Slideshow for main page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, slideshow, imagesource

Any suggestions for programming a Sharepoint 2007 site to use a picture slideshow on the front page?

Comment: I've tried some downloads from the Internet. But, they get too complicated for me. Some need to be purchased and I don't have a budget for this project. So, I was hoping to find some java script or web part to make this work.

Comment: Also, thanks for the recommendation to accept responses. I didn't realize that I needed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SPSlideshow](http://www.spelements.com/spelements.com/spslideshow/) is a JavaScript based free slide show web part for SharePoint.  Nice and easy to implement.

A little more technical, but better results IMO, comes from the [Silverlight Slideshow](http://silverlightslideshow.codeplex.com/releases/view/9559) from Codeplex.  More deployment instructions are on the [SharePoint Evolved](http://www.sharepointevolved.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=27) blog.